# Recommendation for ACL Design: Company With Multiple Locations and Multiple Resources

Tags: php, api, rest, acl

I've been working on an ACL system for the following, and I just can't seem to come up with an elegant solution.

A Company can have multiple locations, and multiple locations may or may not have certain modules/features (Resources) activated.

Users can only be assigned to one company but can be assigned to multiple locations. Each level of the chain should have action permissions. For example Company->addLocation(), Location->addUser(), Resource->doAction().

A Resource/Module will have objects associated to it, so if a new resource object is created at location 1, that resource object is associated to Location 1, and only users with the proper permissions at that location or on that resource should be able to take action.

The problem I'm running into is how to avoid creating new groups/permissions for each company/location that is created. I want the system to be flexible enough to authenticate a request something like so:

```
function Resource_1_Submit()
{
    ACL->isAllowed($User);
    // Continue
}
```

I'm just running around in circles because it seems like the authentication checkpoints are so dynamic that its hard to build a really elegant and simple system. It's like the basic group/role/permission system isn't enough to accomplish an ACL on a complex layout like this.

Here's the structure:

```
Company ( CID-1 )
|  |
|  |--- Company Permission 1 ( P_CID-1 )
|  |--- Company Permission 2 ( P_CID-2 )
|  |--- Company Permission 3 ( P_CID-3 )
|
|---- Location 1 ( LID-1 )
|      |
|      |--- Location Permission 1 ( P_LID-1 )
|      |--- Location Permission 2 ( P_LID-2 )
|      |--- Location Permission 3 ( P_LID-3 )
|      |
|      |---- Resource 1 ( RID-1 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-1 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 2 ( P_RID-2 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-3 )
|      |---- Resource 2 ( RID-2 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-1 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 2 ( P_RID-2 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-3 )
|      |---- Resource 3 ( RID-3 )
|            |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-1 )
|            |--- Resource Permission 2 ( P_RID-2 )
|            |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-3 )
|
|---- Location 2 ( LID-2 )
|      |
|      |--- Location Permission 1 ( P_LID-1 )
|      |--- Location Permission 2 ( P_LID-2 )
|      |--- Location Permission 3 ( P_LID-3 )
|      |
|      |---- Resource 1 ( RID-1 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-1 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 2 ( P_RID-2 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-3 )
|      |---- Resource 3 ( RID-3 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-1 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 2 ( P_RID-2 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-3 )
|      |---- Resource 4 ( RID-4 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-1 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 2 ( P_RID-2 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-3 )
|      |---- Resource 5 ( RID-5 )
|            |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-1 )
|            |--- Resource Permission 2 ( P_RID-2 )
|
|---- Location 3 ( LID-3 )
|      |
|      |--- Location Permission 1 ( P_LID-1 )
|      |--- Location Permission 2 ( P_LID-2 )
|      |--- Location Permission 3 ( P_LID-3 )
|      |
|      |---- Resource 1 ( RID-1 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-1 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 2 ( P_RID-2 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-3 )
|      |---- Resource 3 ( RID-3 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-1 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 2 ( P_RID-2 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-3 )
|      |---- Resource 4 ( RID-4 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-1 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 2 ( P_RID-2 )
|      |      |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-3 )
|      |---- Resource 5 ( RID-5 )
            |--- Resource Permission 1 ( P_RID-1 )
            |--- Resource Permission 2 ( P_RID-2 )
```

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you. Did you come up with a solution?

Comment: I ended up using zizaco/entrust package with a few clever magic methods to check permissions on objects.